# Wrong results switching branches in XCode 4 with Subversion

Tags: xcode, svn, branch, svn-switch

I have a project in XCode 4 using subversion over ssh.  It's configured with the branches, tags and trunk subdirectories and my project (let's say ProjectOne) is its own directory in trunk like so:

```
-|-trunk
 | \- ProjectOne
 |-tags
 \-branches
```

I have the relative paths to the three directories configured in XCode like so:

Trunk : trunk
Branches : branches
Tags : tags

And all three have a green 'light' next to them.  I have created a branch for my project called ProjectOneBeta using the organiser, the svn tree now has this structure:

```
-|-trunk
 | \-ProjectOne
 |-tags
 \-branches
   \-ProjectOneBeta
      \-ProjectOne
```

If I checkout the project (with trunk/ProjectOne selected) it will check out by creating it's own directory in my Objective-C directory.  When I go to switch a branch the structure gets all screwy though.  It then becomes:

```
-ProjectOne
 \-ProjectOne
```

Can anyone help?  Have I checked in the code incorrectly initially?  Should there not have been that initial subdirectory in trunk? Am I checking it out wrong? Or do I simply have the relative paths set incorrectly despite the green?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I concluded that the configuration was correct but the initial checkin was wrong.  I moved all the stuff up one level so the code & project was just in 'trunk'.  Works fine now I just have to remember to check out to a named directory.